# How can I handle a dynamic number of inputs without an increasing number of if statements or switch cases?

Tags: c#, business-logic

I'm working on a little proof of concept project for handling and polling the status of transactions, and have had it pointed out that my current web of `if` statements works OK in the proof of concept stage, but won't hold up or be maintainable as the business logic becomes more complex or more statuses/permutations need to be added.

For a simple example of what I'm working with, here's a function that takes 4 `bool`s as inputs, and different dependent permutations of these will lead to different `enum` values being returned:

```
    public static TransactionStatus GetStatusForValues(bool isOverdue, bool isUrgent, bool isMember, bool isExisting)
    {
        if (isExisting)
        {
            if (isUrgent)
            {
                if (isMember)
                {
                    return TransactionStatus.Expidited;
                }

                return TransactionStatus.Declined;
            }

            if (!isUrgent)
            {
                if (isOverdue)
                {
                    return TransactionStatus.Active;
                }
            }
        }

        if (!isOverdue)
        {
            return TransactionStatus.Active;
        }

        return TransactionStatus.Confirmed;
    }
```

(Don't try and read anything into the domain logic here, this is purely made up rules for the benefit of the example)

This example with a relatively small number of input values is kind of convoluted already. Ideally, I would like to be able to implement something that allowed combinations of values to map to a result status, but without having to use a pile of `if` statements or a `switch` that could quickly become unmanageable.

An idea that's half-formed in my head is to be able to do some kind of rules engine approach, where individual rules could be passed in to represent the different permutations. I also wondered about being able to use something like C#'s `Predicate` class to be able to check multiple conditions.

Comment: is there some shenanigans you can do with Automapper?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need a pipeline.
Each part of the pipeline can be separate and testable in isolation, but you can add whatever pipeline features are required.

```
interface IPipeline
{
    TransactionStatus Next(SomeData somedata);
}

class IsExistingAndUrgent : IPipeline
{
    public TransactionStatus Next(SomeData data)
    {
        if(data.IsExisting && data.IsUrgent)
        {
            if (isMember)
            {
                return TransactionStatus.Expidited;
            }

            return TransactionStatus.Declined;
        }
        else
        {
            Next(somedata);
        }
    }
}

class IsOverDue : IPipeline
{
    public TransactionStatus Next(SomeData somData)
    {
       if(!someData.!isOverdue)
       {
            return TransactionStatus.Active;
       }
       return TransactionStatus.Confirmed;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for funsies - this particular example can be rewritten to something like the following with switch expressions, value tuples and pattern matching:

```cs
static TransactionStatus GetStatusForValues(bool isOverdue, bool isUrgent, bool isMember, bool isExisting) =>
    (isExisting, isUrgent, isMember, isOverdue) switch
    {
        (isExisting: true, isUrgent: true, isMember: true, isOverdue: _) => TransactionStatus.Expidited,
        (isExisting: true, isUrgent: true, isMember: false, isOverdue: _) => TransactionStatus.Declined,
        (isExisting: true, isUrgent: false, isMember: _, isOverdue: true) => TransactionStatus.Active,
        (isExisting: _, isUrgent: _, isMember: _, isOverdue: false) => TransactionStatus.Active,
        _ => TransactionStatus.Confirmed
    };
```

But if number of switches is much bigger or switches will have more states I would consider using some kind of rule engine or state machine - for example based on [`stateless`](https://github.com/dotnet-state-machine/stateless) project.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to tackle these things by writing code that cade be written to be able to be modified at run-time. Then you can inject in new configurations from alternative classes, for from a database, JSON, or XML.

The basic starting point looks like this:

```
private static List<(bool? isOverdue, bool? isUrgent, bool? isMember, bool? isExisting, TransactionStatus transactionStatus)> transactionStatusMap = new()
{
    (null, true, true, true, TransactionStatus.Expidited),
    (null, true, false, true, TransactionStatus.Declined),
    (true, false, null, true, TransactionStatus.Active),
    (false, null, null, null, TransactionStatus.Active),
    (null, null, null, null, TransactionStatus.Confirmed),
};
```

By using `bool?` I have a third state of "don't care" for matching the bool.

So now the `GetStatusForValues` method can be written once and never need to be modified:

```
public static TransactionStatus GetStatusForValues(bool isOverdue, bool isUrgent, bool isMember, bool isExisting) =>
    transactionStatusMap
        .Where(x =>
            (x.isOverdue.HasValue ? isOverdue == x.isOverdue.Value : true)
            && (x.isUrgent.HasValue ? isUrgent == x.isUrgent.Value : true)
            && (x.isMember.HasValue ? isMember == x.isMember.Value : true)
            && (x.isExisting.HasValue ? isExisting == x.isExisting.Value : true))
        .Select(x => x.transactionStatus)
        .First();
```

Calling it doesn't change, so `TransactionStatus ts = GetStatusForValues(true, true, false, true);` works as expected and returns `TransactionStatus.Declined`.

I ran a test to ensure my mapping works:

```
isOverdue | isUrgent | isMember | isExisting | original  | mapped  
--------- | -------- | -------- | ---------- | --------- | ---------
True      | True     | True     | True       | Expidited | Expidited
True      | True     | True     | False      | Confirmed | Confirmed
True      | True     | False    | True       | Declined  | Declined
True      | True     | False    | False      | Confirmed | Confirmed
True      | False    | True     | True       | Active    | Active  
True      | False    | True     | False      | Confirmed | Confirmed
True      | False    | False    | True       | Active    | Active  
True      | False    | False    | False      | Confirmed | Confirmed
False     | True     | True     | True       | Expidited | Expidited
False     | True     | True     | False      | Active    | Active  
False     | True     | False    | True       | Declined  | Declined
False     | True     | False    | False      | Active    | Active  
False     | False    | True     | True       | Active    | Active  
False     | False    | True     | False      | Active    | Active  
False     | False    | False    | True       | Active    | Active  
False     | False    | False    | False      | Active    | Active
```

---

If you wanted to go to an XML-based approach you could consider this XML:

```
<map>
  <if isExisting="true">
    <if isUrgent="true">
      <if isMember="true">
        <then transactionStatus="Expidited" />
      </if>
      <then transactionStatus="Declined" />
    </if>
    <if isUrgent="false">
      <if isOverdue="true">
        <then transactionStatus="Active" />
      </if>
    </if>
  </if>
  <if isOverdue="false">
    <then transactionStatus="Active" />
  </if>
  <then transactionStatus="Confirmed" />
</map>
```

Then populate `transactionStatusMap` like this:

```
transactionStatusMap =
    xdocument
        .Descendants("then")
        .Select(x => new
        {
            transactionStatus = Enum.Parse<TransactionStatus>(x.Attribute("transactionStatus").Value),
            booleans =
                x
                    .Ancestors()
                    .Where(a => a.Name == "if")
                    .SelectMany(
                        x => x.Attributes(),
                        (x, a) => new { name = a.Name.LocalName, value = (bool)a })
                            .Aggregate(new Dictionary<string, bool?>()
                            {
                                { "isOverdue", null },
                                { "isUrgent", null },
                                { "isMember", null },
                                { "isExisting", null },
                            }, (q, z) => { q[z.name] = z.value; return q; })
        })
        .Select(x => (isOverdue: x.booleans["isOverdue"], isUrgent: x.booleans["isUrgent"], isMember: x.booleans["isMember"], isExisting: x.booleans["isExisting"], transactionStatus: x.transactionStatus))
        .ToList();
```